# Get category and Sub_subcategories list using query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How to get a list of Category and subcategories like this:

1 mobile

- apple
- samsung
- nokia

2:Laptops

- Mac
- HP
- Dell
- Sony

3:Tvs

- Samsung

using query builder in controller and foreach loop in view

My Controller

```php
$sub_catagories = DB::table('books_categories')
->join('sub_catagories','sub_catagories.catId','=','books_categories.catId')->get();
return view('index',compact('sub_catagories'));
```

My category table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('catId');
            $table->string('catName', 50)->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My sub_catagory table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sub_catagories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('catId');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: why down vote my question I followed the Rules and it's clearly explained if anyone have problem understanding this question please write it in comment

Comment: Don't know about downvote, but I just didn't understand well.. do you have 3 related  models like A, B, C ?? where A has many B, B has many C. And do you want to get all A-s with their B-s and with their C-s ??   In your query I saw just 2 tables, it mean models

Comment: Also it will be better to put here your models as well, with their relations

Comment: No I only have two tables Category and Subcategories and I want a list of all categories and subcategories below category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some example of whole cycle. There is convention in laravel to use unique auto increment 'id's, and have foreign keys like RELATION_id. So if you want to change the table and column names anyway, you can do that with following to this example:

**Category Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Subcategory Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subcategories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'category_id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**categories table Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->string('name');
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

**subcategories table Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSubcategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // FOREIGN
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->string('name');
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('subcategories');
    }
}
```

**usage in controller**

```
// 1
public function categories()
{
    $categories = Category::all()->get();

    return view('categories', [
        'categories' => $categories,
    ]);
}
// 2
public function catsWithSubcats()
{
    $cats_with_subcats = Category::with('subcategories')->get();

    return view('cats_with_subcats', [
        'categories' => $cats_with_subcats,
    ]);
}
// 3
public function subcatsWithCats()
{
    $subcats_with_cats = Subcategory::with('category')->get();

    return view('subcats_with_cats', [
        'subcategories' => $subcats_with_cats,
    ]);
}
```

If you want to show all categories with their subcategories in the blade, you don't need to use 2nd or 3rd method, just use 1st method. Create "categories.blade.php" inside of "resources/views/..." and write there something like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
        <p>{{ $subcategory->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer and how to show it in view like list?